# Image is not vertically centered

Tags: html, css

Why isn't the image centered in the li? The dimensions of it is 25x25px.

```css
#information-list li {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c0bf;
}

#information-list li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="information-list" class="flat-list">
    <li>
        <img src="images/test.png" />
        <strong>Foo</strong>
    </li>
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using css resets ? If not, there is maybe some default padding and margin on your li objects from the browser itself !

Comment: **The `vertical-align` property [works differently when it's applied to non-table elements](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```css
#information-list li {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c0bf;
    background:transparent url(images/test.png) no-repeat left center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="information-list" class="flat-list">
    <li>
        <strong>Foo</strong>
    </li>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is vertically centered for me (tested your css/markup in Chrome/Firefox/IE)

Do you have a valid doctype?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `vertical-align`, and how it works [here](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/).
As commented by animuson, [here is how](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) you should use inline elements and `vertical-align`.

Essentially, you need to vertically align both inline elements, and you did it on one only.
You should also try to keep `line-height` properties on blocks that contain text.

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MjNG3/) - *I also included some proof that it is in fact centered*

CSS

```css
#information-list li {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c0bf;
}

#information-list li img,
#information-list li span{
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#information-list li span{
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<ul id="information-list" class="flat-list">
    <li>
        <img src="images/test.png" />
        <span>Foo</span>
    </li>
    ...
```

Here's a screenshot

[image: vertical align with inline elements]

## [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) will give us a bit of insight.

[www.w3.org - `line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height):

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.
>   **The minimum height consists of a minimum height above the baseline and a minimum depth below it, exactly as if each line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the element's font and line height properties**. We call that imaginary box a "strut." (The name is inspired by TeX.).
>
> **The height and depth of the font above and below the baseline are assumed to be metrics that are contained in the font.** (For more details, see CSS level 3.)
>
> On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

[www.w3.org - `vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align):

> This property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.
>
> *Note. Values of this property have different meanings in the context of tables. Please consult the section on table height algorithms for details.*
>
> The following values only have meaning with respect to a parent inline element, or to the strut of a parent block container element.
>
> In the following definitions, for inline non-replaced elements, the box used for alignment is **the box whose height is the 'line-height' (containing the box's glyphs and the half-leading on each side, see above).** For all other elements, the box used for alignment is the margin box.

### The default blocks

The HTML you provided consists of 4 blocks which have these `display` properties by default.

- `<ul>` - treated as a `block`
- `<li>` - treated as `list-item`
- `<img>` - is treated as an `inline-block` ([placed as inline, but formatted as a block](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock))
- `<strong>` - treated as `inline`

Try to remember them. Though they have little impact on this particular scenario, it is good to know the [defaults](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display) and [what they do and what they are for](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

See also

> 9.2.2.1 Anonymous inline boxes
>
> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline element.